# No network in Debian 10 on Hyper-V

Tags: debian, networking, hyper-v

Installed Debian 10 on Hyper-V and it is not showing any network. No IP address has been assigned to VM even though I have created an `Internal` type `Virtual Switch Manager` and assigned it to `Network Adapter` of VM.

I even tried with `Legacy Network Adapter` but same result. Below you can see:

[image]

`/etc/network/interfaces` shows:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: This question would likely be better served on Superuser as this issue has more to do with Hyper-V and not your Debian networking configuration. I have a Debian VM on Hyper-V with identical (I am using the default hyper-v network adapter) setup as yours and I have networking. Everything you have matches my version of Debian. Does `ip link set enp0s10f0 up` enable your interface?

Comment: When I run the command you posted, it says `cannot find device enp0s10f0`

Comment: You need to make sure that it is the name of your network interface. I used the name provided in your output. Please confirm that you are pointing to the right one. Mine is `eth0` but I have seen ones with very complicated and random names such as yours above.